# Min Android version for port of iOS game?

Tags: android, android-version

I just completed an iPhone/iOS game ("Ktalu: Planet of Terror"). I would like to port this to Android so I downloaded and installed the Andorid SDK/Eclipse etc. When I create a new project, it asks me the minimum version of Android to be supported. The default is API Level 8 (Froyo).

My iOS game is written in Objective C using Cocos2D version 2.0. It is a single player game, 2D side-scroller, uses the accelerometer for input. It has in-app purchases, and uses code to allow people to post scores on Facebook or Twitter. It uses SoundEngine for sound. It uses GameCenter for a leaderboard and some achievements.

I assume that there are Android equivalents for all (or most) of the above. Also, I don't want to support really old Android versions if few people still have phones that run those.

So can someone suggest what I should use for min Android version to support?

Also, does anyone know where there is any info on the web that talks about how many phones in circulation (in late 2012 or early 2013) use various versions of Android? Again, even if my game technically could support Android Level 8, if there are only 1% of all phones currently out there that run Level 8 or below, then it doesn't make sense to try to support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may choose minimal version now. Eclipse and android documentation will "tell" (in process of porting) you when you'll need higher version. You may change it in few seconds in future.
 Here are some version usage statistics (just Googled for you) http://www.androidtapp.com/tag/android-statistics/

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Looks like for now (early 2013) it is still worthwhile to support Android Level 8, which is the default in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just 'pick' a version, you need to research a version that has all the features you need to use. Just telling us what it uses doesn't help because we don't know what method calls it would use. You can change the min API level as you need functions in newer API levels.